# Nikon D5100 - completely white image

Tags: nikon-d5100

I was reviewing my shots from a day out and noticed that one image was completely white. The shot was the last in a series of about 5 or 6 which were taken in the space of about a minute. The settings were the same for all of them.

The camera is only a few months old so is this a tell-tale sign of something I should get checked out, or just an anomaly that a lot of cameras have?

Also, from what I can remember the camera became unresponsive for a few seconds when this shot was taken (this happened at some time during the day, I'm just putting 2 & 2 together).

Comment: The "camera became unresponsive for a few seconds" bit forces me to think that shutter was open for that duration. Either you unintentionally bumped some setting or some problem with camera metering forced it into a long exposure. Can you provide exif from the washed out image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What settings was it on (should be in the EXIF data for the photo)? If it was manual exposure (intentionally or accidentally) then you can easily end up with an all white shot if you miscalculate. If it was one of the auto settings then it's less likely, but the settings the camera chose might give a clue.

Comment: I think pdbartlett, in simple terms is saying, if the settings were wrong this could leave the camera shutter open to long - over exposing the shot.

Comment: I was using some fairly typical settings, ISO 100, f/4.5, 1/20. It was not the settings though, because this was part of a few photos I took of the same subject in the space of about 1 minute. Might have been an error writing to the card or something similar I guess.

Comment: @pdbartlett you are correct. I thought this was the last in a series but it was actually the first of the next series. The first series was indoors and the second was outdoors and probably forgot to change the settings :-)

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Happy shooting!

Answer (score 0):

Download Google Picasa (or any other software), open the photo and check the following important parameters by going to View menu and then click Properties (if properties are not already visible).

[image]

Comment: as mentioned in my comment for another post ... the settings were not a problem ... I had taken a perfectly good picture about 5 seconds before this one. ISO 100, f/4.5, 1/20.

Comment: it should also be noted that this was not a typically overexposed image, the pixels were not mostly white, they were literally #FFF. Completely white.